# Adding record to MSAcess from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I worked on MYSQL with ASP.NET. Just today started to try SQL commands in MSAccess. I tried the following code for which I am getting an unhandeled exception error. Anybody please check the below and let me know where the error is at.

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\project\Pages\db.mdb";
        OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO accounts(email, password)VALUES(?, ?)", MyConn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "val1";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "val2";
        MyConn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MyConn.Close();
```

I created an Access database with a table accounts and field ID, email and password.

The exact error I am getting is (but I believe that my syntax is correct)

```
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Source Error: 


Line 22:        cmd.Parameters.Add("password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "val2";
Line 23:        MyConn.Open();
Line 24:        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 25:        MyConn.Close();
Line 26:     }
```

Comment: Have you set the FieldID as Pk and AutoIncrement in your database table...

Comment: @m.qayyum - I guess its all will be done automatically by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Password" is a reserved word. Put it inside brackets.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO accounts(email, [password])VALUES(?, ?)", MyConn);
```

Comment: But I don't have any password for my database.

Comment: And database connection is working fine. I tried Connection.Open(); and close with exception handling and passed the test.

Comment: @KarsM - see the code snippet I posted; when using a reserved word in your SQL statement, it needs to be enclosed in brackets.

Comment: For every database should we use brackets while using word password? and is there any other words do have such special cases?

Comment: The link I posted lists all the reserved words used by Access. It's a good practice to enclose object names in brackets if there is any doubt about it being a reserved word in any database you might be targeting so your queries will be more portable.

Comment: Thanks once again Tim. Have a great day.